# 'importRange' is giving rise to "ReferenceError: "importRange" is not defined."

Tags: google-apps-script

Am I doing something wrong here or is `importRange` a method of some other object I am not aware of?

```
var importData=importRange("key of the spreadsheet","required range");
```

When I do this I see:

> ReferenceError: "importRange" is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImportRange](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273) is a function for use in formulas, try using [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula%28String%29) from Apps Script.